Calculate The Sum Of The Infinite Series
Given
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(\frac{x}{2})^{2n-\frac{1}{2}}}{n! \,\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})} 
&= \frac{(\frac{x}{2})^{\frac{-1}{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}{\bigl(\frac{-x}{4}\bigr)}^{4}}{\frac{n!(2n)!\sqrt \pi}{n!\,2^{2n}}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{x}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \bigl(\frac{x^2}{4}\bigr)^n\,4^n\,n!}{n!\,(2n)!\sqrt \pi} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}\bigl(\frac{4x^2}{4}\bigr)^n}{(2n)!} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
\end{aligned}
$$
The expansion
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\,x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
is part of Taylor Series Expansion For $\cos(x)$. This series converges for all real values of $x$.
Hence,
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}} \cos x.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(\frac{x}{2})^{2n-\frac{1}{2}}}{n! \,\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{x}} \cos (x-1). 
\end{aligned}

Is my approach is valid here?
Can this series be obtained through other mathematical techniques?


Hey Professor. Welcome to Math Stack Exchange; with LaTex to write trigonometric functions please use \cos instead of cos etc, and for entering an argument into a square root use \sqrt{xyz} instead of \sqrt(xyz).

@Sahaj Thank you very much, I'm new to this platform and beginner Of LaTex , So I frequently encounter errors in writing LaTex. My apologies for the erros here .

By the process presented it can be stated that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \, t^n}{n! \, \Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \, \cos(2 \, \sqrt{t}). $$
The remaining is:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n! \, \Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)} \, \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{2n-1/2} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{x}} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n! \, \Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)} \, \left( \frac{x^2}{4} \right)^{n} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi \, x}} \, \cos(x).
\end{align}
This is the same result as that of $J_{-1/2}(x)$, where $J_{\pm 1/2}(x)$ are spherical Bessel functions.
For reference:
\begin{align}
S(t) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \, t^n}{n! \, \Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \, n! \, 4^n \, t^n}{\sqrt{\pi} \, n! \, (2 n)!}
 \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \, (2 \sqrt{t})^{2 n}}{(2 n)!} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \, \cos(2 \, \sqrt{t}).
\end{align}
